# AzureDevOps email notifications randomly not working

Tags: email, azure-devops, notifications, azure-devops-server-2019

We are running our own DevOPS Server in some virtuell Windows Server environment.
From time to time (it differs from weeks to months) not a single email gets sent by the server, when e.g. a new WorkItem is assigned to someone or a build pipeline fails.

All co-workers receive their other mails (from anyone) normally as their used to, when this happens.
Connecting via rdp session to the server is also no problem.

It works for a undefined periode of time, after the server gets restarted.
The email account which is used to send the email notifications by the server, is an outlook365 account.

After restarting the whole windows server inside the virtual machine, the emails are getting send and everyone in the company is email bombed than by the server :) whith every mail that didn't get send by azuredevops server from the day when the problem occured (this is not always clear, when it starts, because we are not always recognizing it so fast when it ouccures) until the time we restart the server.

Any one here having any idea, what could i check when the problem occurs again?
thanks for any hint in advance

Comment: Releated: Microsoft's support team had no clue on how to solve their own problem:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-DevOps-Server-202001-User-notifi/10403545